# remember me functionality with specific server topology

Tags: security, authentication

I'm implementing the "remember me" functionality for the client of our product and I'm a bit stuck  with it. Here what we have:

- 3 separated servers, which doesn't comunicate each other.
- A client which needs "remember me" functionality and which is redirected to one of 3 servers at log in.
- That instance, which redirects users, doesn't know anything about authentification or user credentials.

So could you, please, give me some guidline of how can "remember me" implemented in my case? Storing password in cookie is acceptable, but not desirable.

If you need more info about something, please, ask, and I'll try to provide it.

Thanks to everyone for your suggestions!

Comment: do the three servers handle login or a fourth server?

Comment: @user1937198, that 3 servers handle logins, that's why it is some type of problem to implement subject functionality.

Answer (score 2):

This is typically done by having all three servers use a common session storage backend, like a database or memcache.

If you can't easily implement common sessions, you could adjust the code on the redirect server to store the server id of the server that it selected to redirect to in a cookie. Don't store the password in a cookie. For example:

```
    new hit comes in
    if cookie exists:
        forward to the server indicated in cookie
    else:
        pick a random server
        set cookie with the server id you picked
        forward to the server you picked
```

Comment: The pseudocode you provided seems to be a good solution! I'll discuss this with collegues, thank you so much for sharing your experience!